# Deleted \home, files were backed up, computer froze and now I can't log in

Tags: gnome

I was trying to install a program in home and it screwed up my \home directory. All my files were backed up but now I can't use any file manager to organize everything again. The files were moved to a folder called backupdir-8866.

Comment: What is your distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ctrl-alt-f2 to get a text console. log in on the text console and run "startx" to get a gui.

or: log in as root.

as a user on the text console the command `sudo passwd` should allow you to set a root password, after which you should be able to do a GUI login as root.

Comment: After running `startx` i get the error `xauth: timeout in locking authority file //.Xauthority`, and a few more errors.

Comment: hmm.... I guess that mens you need a home directory to start the GUI.

Comment: And make sure the home dir has write permission

Comment: Yes, making a home directory solved my issue and my files were located in the folder i mentioned, thank you.